# What's the best way to create a report on OpenERP

Tags: printing, report, odoo

I try to create a report on OpenERP. There is several methods to do this task (openoffice plugin, XML files, RML files, etc.)

What's the quickest way to do that (and/or the most beautiful) ?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it's programming related. XML, RML, Reportlab, OpenERP... what is it for you ?

Comment: Your question wasn't clearly listed as such.

Comment: @Daniel It's your personal opinion and I absolutely do not share

Comment: Hi @Daniel, the report templates in OpenERP contain a mixture of Python code and Report Markup Language (an XML schema). In my opinion, this question is sufficiently programming related for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SeyZ, I suggest you assume that Daniel's intentions were good and that you don't take the feedback personally. If he were unfamiliar with OpenERP or RML, this question would look like a common report formatting question that would be more appropriate for a site like superuser.com. Of course, that's just my personal opinion and you're absolutely free to not share it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've only used the RML files and I've been happy with the result. I haven't tried the OpenOffice method, but it seems like the conversion step from SXW to RML would be more hassle. When I edit an RML file, I just save it and click on the report button in the client to try it out. No compilation or conversion necessary. OpenOffice might be useful if I wanted to let business users make minor changes to reports, but I suspect that all the weird data extraction code would confuse them.

I haven't tried the XML report technique, so I can't comment on it.

I assume you've seen the [documentation on writing reports](http://doc.openerp.com/v5.0/developer/3_11_reports/index.html). I just noticed a section that talks about changing the corporate default headers, and it only seems to be described for XML reports. I haven't looked any further, but that might be a reason to use XML instead of RML. I know we would like to get rid of the corporate headers for some internal documents.

Answer (score 4):

If you know **html** then **webkit report** using **mako**. Webkit reports are very easy to create compare to rml.

Comment: +1 Go with webkit. waaaay easier to figure out in my experience

Comment: If you want to give it a try this link will be useful for you http://help.openerp.com/question/4724/how-to-configure-webkit-for-v7/. Just for your info. :)

Answer (score 4):

Web kit Report is the easiest way to make a Report, to install webkit report

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

and install report_webkit module in OpenERP, it will show the tab in the company, within company you can make simple report using OpenERP GUI,

for Advance report You must learn the maco template,

Thanks..!!

Comment: Great installation advice! There's a little more to do now as detailed here http://help.openerp.com/question/2467/reporting-with-webkit/

Answer (score 0):

For simple reports I prefer using `rml` reports, by creating an sxw file first and then convert it to rml using the script in the openerp module `base_report_designer`.

For complex report and also for making the report more beautiful, I prefer to use `jasper_reports` module. With the help of `iReport` we can generate beautiful reports. We can also use jdbc datasource which can be connect to our database and pull the data. Subreport is also possible using jasper_reports

There are also other reporting tools like aeroo reports,using xsl file, openoffice plugin etc.

Answer (score 0):

jasper report can be used to create OpenERP report using sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I have shown in my post which describes creating a report based on SQL query in OpenERP 7. Please follow this link for the details. Hope this will help others.

http://sajjadhossain.com/2013/06/30/openerp-7-creating-report-using-sql-query/

Answer (score -1):

the most easiest and simple and quickest way to edit,customize and create your own report is editing the .rml files knowledge from experience so far