# OpenERP basic reports

Tags: reporting, odoo

OpenERP is one of the best ERP applications I ever used.

I found that almost everything must be built from the beginning to meet the specific needs for each one including the analysis reports, but there are some basic packages already built.

Since I am new to OpenERP functionality and still haven't learned how to create reports in OpenERP, I need to know if there is any addons/extra module that provides me some basic and ready to print reports and listings for the several modules. This reports and listings will help me to better understand and learn the functional part of the application and will allow me on a future to better understand how to build reports and listings in OpenERP.

If anyone can provide me a link or repository with such information I will be greatfull.

Thank you very much

Regards

Paulo Matos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various ways of creating reports with openerp. They are (i've prioritized)

- Webkit (for html,web designers - this will be a great utility)
- OpenOffice  (for any office person with minimal technical skills)
- RML  (Strictly for programmers :))
- Jasper Report (good for people with java-reporting base)
- Aeroo (Rich functionality of exporting to excel,word etc, still i am not comfortable in aeroo with openerp 7)
- Pentaho Report Designer  (A reporting tool from pentaho )

These links will help you in understanding better, setup environment and learn from the sample modules and reports. However you need to design what u need with one of the reporting type.

[What's the best way to create a report on OpenERP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922993/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-report-on-openerp)

http://www.schenkels.nl/2013/02/custom-reports-in-openerp-what-will-you-use/

http://colinnewell.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/adding-new-reports-to-openerp/

https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports/

https://doc.openerp.com/6.1/book/8/8_20_Config/8_20_Config_reports/

Google more. You'll get everything u need. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Reporting from Odoo / OpenERP can be very frustrating at times.  We have found over the years that no single solution is great for every need.

The built in reporting mechanisms mentioned in the first answer (rml / openoffice) have been somewhat deprecated and replaced with qweb reporting which renders similarly in HTML or PDF.  They can be difficult to get fine-grained control and alignment, a lot of work to achieve non-regular reporting structures and cross tab reports, but are fast and easy to use for straightforward "document" type reports (such as orders / invoices).

I cannot comment on Jasper or Aeroo, as I have not used them.

Using Pentaho Reports for Odoo can be great because they are primarily reporting engines.  They can do wonderful things with data, present them in great ways.

One upside with this connector is its ability to access Data using the object layer, or SQL, or both in one report if necessary (using sub-reports for example), as well as custom methods!

One downside we have found with Pentaho Reporting is that as the code base changes for OpenERP/Odoo, the connector changes, and configuration has to be continually re-vesited.

The latest version supports Odoo version 8 and version 5.4 of Pentaho reporting engine.